# What should be the best technology to be used for creating simple puzzles for a website

Tags: flash, html, html5-canvas, game-engine

We have a website for kids. We want to add few puzzles/games for kids. We want capability so that we can save high scores achieved in our mysql database.

Bit confused what technology to be used. If we use HTML5 we do not get lots of flexibility as it is not powerful enough like flash. Also, browser compatibility issues.

If we use Flash; it has its own challenges.. slowly people are going away from it.. and as we know iOS doesnt support it at all.

Considering all pros and cons; what is the best technology to be used. It can be anything other than html5 or flash too .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 is the way to go for web delivery.
Kids especially are using tablets and mobile devices for browsing, and Windows 8 metro won't support flash (for the most part) either.

There are lots of frameworks out now that can ease the burden of cross browser issues and performance.  Things like easleJS or raphael.

Flash is more elegant and faster and more consistent yes, but you can accomplish just about everything now with most modern browsers.

Look at Grant Skinners EasleJS and his other supporting libraries and see if that will work for you specific game needs.

http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS

Answer (score 1):

I would go with HTML5 simply because it has the capability to cover most of the requirements that you might have vis-a-vis creating puzzles/games for kids. There are various libraries available as pointed out above i.e. RaphaelJS, etc.

For some simple tutorials on using basic HTML5 Canvas stuff to create puzzle/quiz in HTML5, here are some links:

- http://www.flashbynight.com/tutes/html5quiz/
- http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2012/08/01/tutorial-puzzle-game-basics-with-html5-and-javascript/